# NGINX Subdomains Redirecting to Main

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, server, config, web-hosting

I am pretty new to NGINX and have a background with Apache. My company is deploying a server that hosts multiple websites. Specifically libretime in one webroot, and our corporate website in the default webroot.

I am having a heck of a time trying to configure the subdomain. I have ruled out cloudflare and I have the DNS set correctly but it just wont go.

I have created two configs in sites-available and simlinked them. Each going to the respective webroot. I also have configured both the main domain and subdomain with SSL.

Whenever I try and go to the subdomain "https://radio.example.com" it gets redirected to "https://example.com" and never allows me to go to the subdomain.

Please see the below config files, any help would be appreciated as im getting conflicting info.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;
  server_name www.example.com example.com;
  server_name_in_redirect on;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  root /var/www/html/example.com;

  if ($scheme = http) {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  client_max_body_size 512M;
  client_body_timeout 300s;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    # try_files $uri =404;
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }
}
```

Second Subdomain

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;
  server_name radio.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://radio.example.com$request_uri;
  server_name_in_redirect on;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/libretime.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/libretime.error.log;

  root /usr/share/libretime/legacy/public;

  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  client_max_body_size 512M;
  client_body_timeout 300s;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    # try_files $uri =404;
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/libretime-legacy.sock;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ ^/api/(v2|browser) {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/libretime-api.sock;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the output of `curl -IL https://radio.example.com` to the question.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire Nginx configuration across all included files and ensure that both `server` blocks are represented with the correct `listen` and `server_name` directives. Use `curl` to test the site and add the results together with the associated access log entries and any error log entries.